# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session when trying to initialize

Tags: java, hibernate, initialization, lazy-initialization

I have an entity that's LAZY fetch called Player. I'm trying to manually have hibernate initialize it but I'm getting that error as if I'm trying to use the Player entity before it's initialized. Here's an example where I'm getting the error on the first line:

```
    if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(contest.getPlayer())) Hibernate.initialize(contest.getPlayer());
    playerName = contest.getPlayer().getName();
```

(note, making the Player entity EAGER fetch is not an option as it causes far too much latency issues)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Hibernate.initialize() outside transaction. You may use Hibernate.initialize right afrer you get query result (i mean in the same transaction) or if you want to initialize it later - write separate query to fetch player.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to mention, this part of code has the @Transactional annotation.